# Umbraco + YAF integration - connection issues

Tags: umbraco, yetanotherforum

I'm working to try and get a migrated Umbraco/YAF installation working, but I'm having issues with connectivity.

I've already asked for help with the [Connection Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148839/), so this bit is sorted.

However, I still get a 404 error when I try and navigate to `mysite/forums`, as it redirects to `mysite/install`

[This site](http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postst7659_Forum-is-auto-redirecting-to-install-folder.aspx) tells me that this could be because of a few issues:

```
It will connect you to install\default.aspx if 
: its connect to a db but thinks there isn't a YAF version present in its data, or
: database version doesn't match and thinks it needs updating.
```

I know it's connecting to the DB, because the CMS connection string works, and it's connecting to the same database.

There are YAF_* tables in the database, so I know it's content is there.

By process of elimination, it might be a version issue, but I'm not sure how to compare the DB version to the ASP files version.

I'm running Umbraco 4.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never quite worked out what version I was running, but I did find out this issue was fixed by:

```
Assign yaf database user db-owner privileges.
```

And there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

check that you have the following line in web.config

```
<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="4.6.1" />
```

Comment: Yes, it's 4.6.1. This is also reflected in the Umbraco 'About' popup.