# SqlConnection error "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to import an Excel file into my database using ASP.NET MVC, but I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

about the connection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
```

in this part of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RéceptionEntities"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    string query = "Insert into Réception_camions(Date_d_arrivée,heure_d_arrivée,Poids_cam,Id_cam,Id_qualité) Values('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString() + "')";

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

My connection string :

```
<add name="RéceptionEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MVCTutorialModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MVCTutorialModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MVCTutorialModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LOl-PC\connect;initial catalog=Réception;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

How to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Well since we can't see the value for your connection string we probably can't help much other than tell you it's probably malformed. Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6148969/7948962) may help?

Comment: What is the format of your connection string?

Comment: I edited my question and I added the connection string. please see it again.

Comment: Your connection string for connecting via `SqlConnection` should be `data source=LOl-PC\connect;initial catalog=Réception;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

Comment: How to change the syntax , thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have as a connetion string is for Database-first connection. That works well for EF, but does not work for `SqlConnection`.

So what you need to do is to have 2 connection strings - keep one existing, and add another one like this:

```
<add name="RéceptionEntities_SQL" 
     connectionString="data source=LOl-PC\connect;initial catalog=Réception;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And when you need to connect to your DB with raw SQL, you just reference the other connection string:

```
var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RéceptionEntities_SQL"].ConnectionString;
var con = new SqlConnection(conn);
```

Just need to remember to update both of the connection strings when you deploy or update one of the strings.

Here is some reading:

- [Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings)
- [Connection String Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)
- [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)
- [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6148839/809357)